# How do I get the path to a directory of an image file and how do I get the name of the image?

Tags: 8, uri

I am new to Drupal and new to `twig`. I am currently using Drupal 8.1.1. I would like to obtain two things, the directory path of the image and the image name. I can get the path to the image using twig:

```
{{ file_url(content.field_image['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}
```

Is there a way to do this? For example, I get `/path/to/image.jpeg` using `file_url()`, is there any function to return /path/to, the path to the image directory and the image name?

Comment: Keep open, after re-reading the Q carefully, it is not a duplicate, he just wants the /path/to without the image.jpeg part

Comment: I would also like to know if it's possible to just get the file name?